# Can you modify multiple entities in an observable array, but have Knockout fire only a single change notification?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have an observable array from which I need to remove one item and add another. If I just call `.remove(myItem)` on the observable array and then push my new item onto it, Knockout will **fire two change notifications** for that array, but in this case **I would rather see this as a single change**, firing only one notification.

What I've done to accomplish this is that I take out the underlying array and keep it in a temporary variable, I then do the modifications to that temporary variable, and when I'm done I put the whole thing back into the observable array. Something like this (somewhat simplified from what I actually do):

```
vm.MyArray = ko.observableArray(["foo", "bar"]);

// Later when I need to alter the observable array, I do something like this    
var temp = vm.MyArray();
temp.splice(0, 1);
temp.push("some");
vm.MyArray(temp);
```

Though this accomplish my goal, it doesn't feel like the right way of doing it.

**Is there a more proper way to make multiple changes to an observable array, but only have a single notification fired?**

*Update:*

The reason I don't want two notifications fired is because I subscribe to changes on the array, and make an AJAX-request to load new data whenever it changes. Because of this, I don't want to fire unnecessary notifications. I don't want notifications to be fired until I'm "done" editing the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve such behavior you should work with unwrapped observable array and then call `valueHasMutated` method:

```
vm.MyArray = ko.observableArray(["foo", "bar"]);
vm.MyArray().remove(myItem);
vm.MyArray().push(newItem);
vm.MyArray.valueHasMutated();
```

Comment: Where does the unwrapped come into your example?

Comment: Ah, right, I thought that you meant explicitly use the unwrapped utils method. Nice!